# Error with Delegate VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a class which will detect what mouse button was pressed each time, but I'm getting 2 errors in the Hookmouse() sub which regards to delegates. Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong ? I would really aprreciate if someone could explain me more about delegates except from correcting this piece of code.

The 2 errors I get:

> Method 'Private Function MouseProc(nCode As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As MouseHook.MouseHookStruct) As Integer' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Function MouseHook.MouseProcDelegate(nCode As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As MouseHook.MouseHookStruct) As Integer'.
>
> Value of type 'MouseHook.MouseProcDelegate' cannot be converted to 'MouseHook.CallBack'.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class MouseHook
    Public Delegate Function CallBack(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As MouseHookStruct) As Integer
'Declare the mouse hook constant.
'For other hook types, obtain these values from Winuser.h in Microsoft SDK.
Dim WH_MOUSE As Integer = 7
Shared hHook As Integer = 0

'Keep the reference so that the delegate is not garbage collected.
Private hookproc As CallBack

'Import for the SetWindowsHookEx function.
<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Overloads Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx _
      (ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As CallBack,
       ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As Integer
End Function

'Import for the CallNextHookEx function.
<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Overloads Shared Function CallNextHookEx _
      (ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer,
       ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As MouseHookStruct) As Integer
End Function
'Import for the UnhookWindowsHookEx function.
<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Overloads Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx _
          (ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
Private Delegate Function MouseProcDelegate(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As MouseHookStruct) As Integer



'Point structure declaration.
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Public Structure Point
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
End Structure

'MouseHookStruct structure declaration.
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Public Structure MouseHookStruct
    Public pt As Point
    Public hwnd As Integer
    Public wHitTestCode As Integer
    Public dwExtraInfo As Integer
End Structure
Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL As Integer = 14
Private Const WM_MOUSEMOVE As Integer = &H200
Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H201
Private Const WM_LBUTTONUP As Integer = &H202
Private Const WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = &H203
Private Const WM_RBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H204
Private Const WM_RBUTTONUP As Integer = &H205
Private Const WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = &H206
Private Const WM_MBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H207
Private Const WM_MBUTTONUP As Integer = &H208
Private Const WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = &H209
Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL As Integer = &H20A

Private MouseHook As Integer
Private MouseHookDelegate As MouseProcDelegate

Public Event Mouse_Move(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Left_Down(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Left_Up(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Left_DoubleClick(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Right_Down(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Right_Up(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Right_DoubleClick(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Middle_Down(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Middle_Up(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Middle_DoubleClick(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
Public Event Mouse_Wheel(ByVal ptLocat As Point, ByVal Direction As Wheel_Direction)

Public Enum Wheel_Direction
    WheelUp
    WheelDown
End Enum

Private Function MouseProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As MouseHookStruct) As Integer
    If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
        Select Case wParam
            Case WM_MOUSEMOVE
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Move(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Left_Down(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_LBUTTONUP
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Left_Up(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Left_DoubleClick(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_RBUTTONDOWN
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Right_Down(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_RBUTTONUP
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Right_Up(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Right_DoubleClick(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_MBUTTONDOWN
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Middle_Down(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_MBUTTONUP
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Middle_Up(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Middle_DoubleClick(lParam.pt)
            Case WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                Dim wDirection As Wheel_Direction
                If lParam.hwnd < 0 Then
                    wDirection = Wheel_Direction.WheelDown
                Else
                    wDirection = Wheel_Direction.WheelUp
                End If
                RaiseEvent Mouse_Wheel(lParam.pt, wDirection)
        End Select
    End If
    Return CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)
End Function
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook)
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub

Public Sub HookMouse()
    MouseHookDelegate = New MouseProcDelegate(AddressOf MouseProc)
    MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookDelegate, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)
End Sub

Public Sub UnhookMouse()
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook)
End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: And what are the two errors? Please add this very important info.

Comment: BC31143 Method 'Private Function MouseProc(nCode As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As MouseHook.MouseHookStruct) As Integer' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Function MouseHook.MouseProcDelegate(nCode As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As MouseHook.MouseHookStruct) As Integer'.                      BC30311 Value of type 'MouseHook.MouseProcDelegate' cannot be converted to 'MouseHook.CallBack'.

Comment: ByRef missing, forgotten?

Comment: Where am I missing ByRef ?

Comment: Intentionally mis-declaring a pinvoke function is a strategy, but it causes too many problems here since it is not done consistently.  Many other problems as well.  Throw this away, use Nuget instead.

Comment: According to [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT), `MouseHookStruct` should have `hwnd` and `dwExtraInfo` as `IntPtr`.

Comment: You have `ByRef lParam As MouseHookStruct` in your `MouseProc` function but `ByVal lParam As MouseHookStruct` in your `MouseProcDelegate` delegate. Both should be `ByVal`.